# Dynamically invoke a method from a varying class

Tags: java

I have a requirement where in i need to invoke method from class in a particular pattern which is obtained as input argument.

```
   public RandomMethod(String ClassName){
        //Eg For Class Name Abc , there is a method AbcProcessor which i need to invoke
        ClassName.ClassNameProcessor    
        }
```

Since i am getting the argument as String , i am not able to figure out how to cast String into a form where i can call something like **Abc.AbcProcessor()**

I believe there is some way to do this using reflections. But i am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Read up on [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Comment: Use a search engine and search for `java reflection static method`

Comment: Why don't you make the classes `Singletons` and let them implement an interface with the method `process()` defined? Then you could pass the singleton instance and call `singleton.process()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reflection you can do that, try following sample:

Class A:

```
public class A {
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}
```

Class B:

```
public class B {
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("B");
    }    
}
```

Invoking `print()` from A and B:

```
public class Test {

    public static void callPrint(String className){
        try {
            Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
            Object obj = clazz.newInstance();
            clazz.getDeclaredMethod("print").invoke(obj);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        callPrint("test.A");
        callPrint("test.B");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to use reflecton, indeed**:

```
public void randomMethod(String fullyQualifiedClassName, String methodName) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(fullyQualifiedClassName);

    clazz.getMethod(methodName).invoke(null);
}
```

which would work assuming you are calling public static method with no arguments

Comment: This does not work. The classname would have to be qualified (with the package name), and the method is not always called `AbcProcessor`.

Comment: Of course fully qualified name. Technically correct binary name. Will correct the argument methodName. It's not obvious from his description.

Comment: This seems to work partially, but i am getting NullPointer exception since i am passing null as argument for invoke. Any work around for this

Comment: with your current level of expierence, i think that task is too complex right now. You should start with programming basics intstead.

Comment: I do agree, reflection is not that trivial, definitely not recommended for beginners.